# What should be the preferred and efficient way to use database in android?

Tags: android

I have created a database for my application. I will use the data in this database, again and again. I just want to know the preferred way to do this.

One way is to query the database again and again, and the other way in my mind is to have multiple ArrayList for different fields, or something like that, to store data in the start of application in these Lists and then access these Lists whenever I need data(sort of a disconnected mode e.g. DataSets that we have in .Net).

So, which is the efficient way or is there any 3rd better way?

Comment: How much data are we talking about? Is it only read only data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your database local, local and external (shipped to your apk) or remote? If it is local then you can query the database everytime you need. Because you rather have operation with your CPU than keep memory occupied. When it comes to remote database than you can implement various ideas about keeping the last query in case of disconnection, then on the next query release the last query results (not good to me, because you might have milion of results, which will occupy so much memory [scenario]), or save the query results (get result - translate into query for your own database = long process). Or you can query again the database again and again, with least effort so many results. I hope you get my idea and will serve you.